# help in changing my account details

Tags: battle.net

Is there any way I can change my age for my battle net account. I accidentally put the wrong year in. Just wondering if this is a possibility, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. *However*, Blizzard's support department **may** be able to.

You will need to contact Blizzard via the battle.net site appropriate to your region (EU, US, etc...). Once you're on your region's battle.net site follow the support links to get to the correct department: **Support** > **Account, App & Shop** > **Account** > **Change Account Details**.

Be prepared to provide proof that you are the account holder/proof of identity and proof of your date of birth.

Comment: Yes, (based on own experience) Blizzard staff *can* do that after you provided some proof.